# Nav bar appearing and disappearing on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, navbar

So I am trying to make a nav bar which is hidden when you first load the page and displays when you scroll down to the second section, I have got it working but when you scroll up and down within the home section, the nav bar keeps appearing and disappearing again when it should stay out of sight.

Live Demo: http://zimxtrial.ukbigbuy.com/

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var startY= jQuery('#home').position().top + jQuery('#home').outerHeight();
jQuery('#nav-container').html( jQuery('#nav').html());
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > startY ){
        jQuery('#nav-container').slideDown();
    }else{
        $('#nav-container').css({display: 'block'});
        jQuery('#nav-container').slideUp();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#nav-container {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
    display: none;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks guys.

Also, this is my first time messing around with JQuery and JS so be kind.

Final version after fix:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var startY= $('#home').position().top + $('#home').outerHeight();
var navc = $('#nav-container')
navc.html( $('#nav').html());
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > startY ){
        navc.slideDown();
    }else{
        navc.slideUp();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just by the way, you can use `$` as a shortcut `jQuery`, i.e. `$(document).ready()`. Saves on a lot of typing.

Comment: Please save the your jQuery('#nav-container') in a variable out of your scroll function, because you force jQuery to reparse all your data each time you scroll :/

Comment: Thank you both, if you check in my original question I have added a final version which works and has both of your suggestions in it.

Comment: Thank you, glad I learnt that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are inside the `.scroll()` function which gets fired everytime the page is scrolled, it will be going to your else condition and displaying the navbar each time because of this line:

`$('#nav-container').css({display: 'block'});`

Remove this line and it should work as expected.

Comment: This has fixed it, thank you, this is the first thing I have done with JS and didn't realise that slideDown() sets display to block, I need to sit down and do a lot more research about it but I have a bit of a time restraint with this one but definitely want to get better with JS, I only started CSS a couple of months ago, this time last year I was using tables for layout... I have come far.

Comment: @TristanD27 No problem, it's good to hear you have moved on from tables! I can highly recommend looking through the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), especially the [events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) and [effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/), and taking them into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), which is a great tool to allow you to test the methods and see what behaviors they have.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will defiantly look through that and have a play on JSFiddle, now that I am comfortable with divs and CSS I think it is time to learn JS so I can make much better looking sites.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check if the navBar is show or not and depending on that run the scroll() function only if the state is the correct one. Something like this:

```
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > startY && $("#nav-container").css('display') == "none" ){
        jQuery('#nav-container').slideDown();
    }else if( && $("#nav-container").css('display') == "block"){
        $('#nav-container').css({display: 'block'});
        jQuery('#nav-container').slideUp();
    }
```

Comment: You should not need to do this as `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` will be setting the display to `none` and `block` respectively anyway.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help.

When I try that I get an error on the line:
}else if( && $("#nav-container").css('display') == "block"){